# Can't upload image in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, upload

Every now and then I get this error where I am unable to upload images into the CKeditor. 
Sometimes switching browsers will help. 
I have no issue importing images in mosaico templates for example...
Why is this happening and how can I troubleshoot it?

[image]

Comment: Check access or error log for more information

Comment: Checked the Drupal error log and the CIvi Configandlog file. Didn't see anything

Comment: I meant apache2/nginx error and access logs

Comment: logs don't show anything